# Already active transaction in PDO exception handling

Tags: php, pdo

I have a method which is called in a loop to store person objects in a database. Sometimes the loop breaks with the error:

```
There is already an active transaction.
```

I think it has something to do with my exception handling:

```
class MainClass {
  public function doWork() {
    foreach ($persons as $person) {
      try {
        $importer->storePerson($person);
      } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        Log::err($e->getMessage());
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

class Importer {
  public function storePerson(Person $person) {
    try {
      $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
      $this->executeInsert($person);
      $this->executeAnotherInsert($person);
      $this->pdo->commit();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      $this->pdo->rollBack();
      throw $e;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should check if the [commit](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) was successful or not. Maybe [close the cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php). And it's [rollBack()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php).

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? Which cursor?

Comment: Or is the exception handling correct and it's a problem that I started my application twice to let the imports run parallel?

Comment: I'm saying to check the value returned from `$this->pdo->commit()` and `$this->pdo->rollBack()`. Usually when you do an insert, you use a [statement handler](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). If so maybe [close the cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php). Have you tried running your imports not in parallel but sequentially? If so, does the error happen?

Answer (score 1):

Fix at `$this->pdo->roolBack();` to  `$this->pdo->rollBack();`